# Storing object attributes in SQLite with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, activerecord

I use Rails 3.0.5, and created a "User" model and a "Users" controller. The user model has 3 attributes: name, email and confidence_score, with validation tests for the 3.

When I open a Rails console (not in sandbox), I create a new user using:

```
user1 = User.create!(:name => "Oli", :email => "oli@me.com", :confidence_score => 3)
```

there's no error messages, and user1 is saved in the database with an ID, BUT with name and email fields set to NIL, whereas the confidence score field is set to 3, as expected...

If I type in the console: `user1.name`, I receive `=> "Oli",` as an answer, but if I type `user1`, I received the full description of the user instance, with the name and the email fields being nil (confidence score, created at and updated at have the right values...)

### Any clue on what is happening to me ?

Ooops, I just noticed I had written

> attr_accessor

instead of `attr_accessible` for these two fields  :-/

Many thanks for the quick feedback and sorry about that, but I had been trying to understand for hours ! ...

Comment: Can you add your migration to the question?